# remove html div that added dynamically using jquery remove

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, removechild

I am trying to remove a div that is added dynamically by using '+' so, this is "add more" operation in jQuery. I am able to add a new div but when I click on remove icon that is '-' icon It was not getting removed.

My HTML:

```
<?php if(isset($salary_template_deductions) && count($salary_template_deductions)>0) {
      $loop_count_d = 1;
      foreach($salary_template_deductions as $d_key=>$d_val){ ?>
<div class="rowdeduction<?php echo $loop_count_d; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="deduction_id[]" value="<?php echo $d_val->deduction_id; ?>">
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="deductions_label[]" id="deductions_label<?php echo $loop_count_d; ?>" value="<?php echo $d_val->deduction_label; ?>" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-5">
    <input type="text" class="form-control deductions_amount" name="deductions_amount[]" id="deductions_amount<?php echo $loop_count_d; ?>" value="<?php echo $d_val->deduction_amount; ?>" >
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2" >
    <button type="button" data-id="<?php echo $loop_count_d; ?>" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn_remove_deductions"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    <?php if($loop_count_d==count($salary_template_deductions)){  ?>
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs salary-btn salary-btn-allowances-add add_deductions" id="add_deductions_<?php echo $loop_count_d; ?>" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
         </button>
    <?php } ?>
  </div>
</div>
<?php $loop_count_d++; } } ?>
<div class="dynamic_deductions_html"></div>
```

My jQuery Code:

Add More('+') JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var i = <?php echo count($salary_template_allowances); ?>;
  var j = <?php echo count($salary_template_deductions); ?>;
  $(document).on('click', '.add_deductions', function(){
    j++;
    var current_id = $(this).attr('id');
    $('#'+current_id).remove();
    <?php $loop_count_d++; ?>
    var dynamicHTMLDeductions = '<div class"rowdeduction'+j+'"><div class="col-sm-5"> <input type="text" class="form-control" id="deductions_label'+j+'" name="deductions_label[]" placeholder="Enter Deductions Label"></div><div class="col-sm-5">  <input type="text" class="form-control deductions_amount" id="deductions_amount'+j+'" name="deductions_amount[]" value="" placeholder="Enter Deductions Value"></div><div class="col-sm-2"><button type="button" data-id="'+j+'" class="btn btn-danger btn-xs btn_remove_deductions"><i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i></button><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs salary-btn salary-btn-deductions-add add_deductions" id="salary-btn-allowances-add" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button></div></div>';
    $('.dynamic_deductions_html').append(dynamicHTMLDeductions);
  });
});
```

Remove(-) JS code:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove_deductions', function(){
   console.log('clicked on remove');
   j--;
   var previous_row_id = j;
   console.log('previous_row_id'+previous_row_id);
   <?php $loop_count_d--; ?>
   var id = $(this).data('id');
   $(this).closest("div.rowdeduction"+id).remove();
   // $(".rowdeduction"+id).remove();
   $('.rowdeduction'+previous_row_id).find('.col-sm-2').append('<button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-xs salary-btn salary-btn-deductions-add add_deductions" id="salary-btn-deductions-add" ><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>');
});
```

Screenshot:

[image]

I have been running out of time with this small issue but it seems wasting my time on this. Anyone, please assist. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: add UI screenshot

Comment: you have missed `=` in `var dynamicHTMLDeductions = '<div class"rowdeduction'+j+'">` after class attribute.  it should be `var dynamicHTMLDeductions = '<div class="rowdeduction'+j+'">`

Comment: Side note: `var current_id = $(this).attr('id'); $('#'+current_id).remove();` <= this is unnecessary.  `this` is already the element that will be found by looking up the element by its own id.  Just `$(this).remove()` it.

Comment: It's just a '=' missing problem, it seems working now. but I am unable to found that becoz it was not a bug so I couldn't find it. Thanks @jagad89 ok I got your suggestion and thank you too @ Taplar

Comment: @PrasadPatel welcome